# Element addressing within a DataTemplate from a ContentControl

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, contentcontrol

How do I access an element contained in a DataTemplate that is displayed through a ContentControl.  I have a ContentControl which hosts a PresentationModel along the lines of:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                Content="{Binding}" 
                ContentTemplate="{Binding ContentControlTemplate, ElementName=this}"
```

Where "this" is the view (UserControl).

There's a DataGridControl I want to EndEdit on, so I tried this:

```
ContentPresenter presenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this. ContentContainer, 0) as ContentPresenter;
DataGridControl dg = this. ContentContainer.ContentTemplate.FindName("datagrid", presenter) as DataGridControl;
dg.EndEdit();
```

Problem is that the ContentControl has no children, maybe because of the way the content is bound?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are casting the result of GetChild to a ContentPresenter.  Depending on its Template, this may not be the case.  I think its default template includes a Border, so your cast will return null.  If you don't need it to do anything other than display the content, why not use ContentPresenter directly?

Comment: The statement "VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this. ContentContainer, 0)" returns null, it has no children for some reason, even before the cast.

I didn't think to try the Contentpresenter directly, I'll give that a go.

Thanks